# Does dimension of derivative should agree with dimension of variable?

Tags: derivatives

Suppose variable $x$ is a N*1 vector, $A$ is a M*N matrix and $b$ is a M*1 vector.

$$
f(x) = \|e^{Ax} - b \|_2^2
$$

Does its derivative should be like following?
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2*(e^{Ax} - b)*A^T*e^{Ax}
$$

If it is, but the dimension of its derivative doesn't equal to the dimension of $x$. How to explain that? Thanks!

Comment: How do you define $e^{Ax}$?

Comment: This is simply the exponential value for each entry in vector $Ax$.

Comment: I think the best explanation here is that your formula for the derivative is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I found the solution from your hint. Since here $e^{Ax}$ is a element-wise operator, therefore the derivative is not equal to $A^T e^{Ax}$. However, it should be $A .* e^{Ax}$, which is in M*N dimension. This can be proved by definition when you express $e^{Ax}$ in matrix form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My formula for the gradient writes

$$2\sum_i (\exp((Ax)_i-b_i))\exp( (Ax)_i)\vec a_i$$
with the column-vector $\vec a_i$ is given by $(\vec a_i)_j = A_{ij}$.

**Edit**
$$\partial_{x_j}\|e^{Ax}-b\|^2 =  \sum_i\partial_{x_j}(\exp((Ax)_i)-b_i)^2 $$
$$=2 \sum_i(\exp((Ax)_i)-b_i)\partial_{x_j}\exp((Ax)_i) =  2 \sum_i(\exp((Ax)_i)-b_i) \partial_{x_j}\exp\left(\sum_kA_{ik}x_k\right)$$
$$=2 \sum_i(\exp((Ax)_i)-b_i)  \exp\left(\sum_kA_{ik}x_k\right)A_{ij}.$$

Comment: Can you show some more details?

Comment: @Jinfeng please, see edits.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself eventually. Since here $e^{Ax}$ is a element-wise operator, therefore the derivative is not equal to $A^T e^{Ax}$. However, it should be $A .* e^{Ax}$, which is in M*N dimension. This can be proved by definition when you express $e^{Ax}$ in matrix form.